# Получить параметр и отправить его

Tags: delphi, indy

Здравствуйте. Проверяю текст на уникальность, подсказанным мне способом http://text.ru/api-check/manual#ac-link-topic-1 . Необходимо получить параметр text_uid , а затем далее его отправить в виде uid , подскажите как это реализовать?

```
procedure TForm6.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 post: TStringList;
  post_zapros:string;
 begin
 post:=TstringList.Create;
 IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects:=true;
 try
 post:= TStringList.Create;    
 post.Add('text=' + Form6.Memo1.text);    
 post.Add('userkey=e05eb8486456b1ed9e6a384556b7716f');    
 post_zapros:=IdHTTP1.Post('http://api.text.ru/post',post);    
 except    
end;
 end;
end.
```

Получается нужно грубо говоря выловить ответ на Post запрос

Так же сейчас присутсвует ошибка:

> {"error_code":112,"error_desc":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0435\u0440\u044f\u0435\u043c\u044b\u0439
> \u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442
> \u0441\u043b\u0438\u0448\u043a\u043e\u043c
> \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0438\u0439"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка -> "Проверяемый текст слишком короткий".

У вас утечка памяти размером с 2х`TStringList`. Вы его, зачем-то, 2 раза создаете и ни разу не освобождаете.

Ответ сервера на ваш запрос ищите в свойствах начинающихся с `Response...`. `ResponseText`, `ResponseCode` и `Response`.

Как-то так: `Form6.Memo1.text := IdHTTP1.ResponseText;`

Никогда так не делайте:

```
except
end;
```

Лучше так:

```
post := TStringList.Create;
try
  IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
  post.Add('text=' + Form6.Memo1.text);
  post.Add('userkey=e05eb8486456b1ed9e6a384556b7716f');
  try
    post_zapros := IdHTTP1.Post('http://api.text.ru/post', post);
  except
    on E: Exception do
     ShowMessage(E.Message); // лучше так чем вообще ничего 
  end;
finnaly
  post.Free;
end;
```

Comment: ответ получает такой HTTP/1.1 200 OK